# Java - pressing a direction key and having it move smoothly

Tags: keylistener

When I press a direction key to move the object in that direction, it moves once, pauses momentarily, then moves again. Kind of like how if I want to type "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", I would hold "a" key down, but after the first "a" there is a pause then the rest of the "a"'s are typed. How do I remove that pause in KeyListener? Thank you.

Comment: That's an operating system setting.  Has nothing to do with KeyListener.

Answer (score 1):

This is the key repetition feature that the OS provides, so there is no way around the pauses.
The way most games gets around this is to keep an array of the current state of all required keys and check periodically on them (for example in the game loop) and act on that (e.g move).

```
public class KTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    private boolean[] keyState = new boolean[256];

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new KeyTest();

        int xVelocity = 0;

        int x = 0;

        while(1) {
            xVelocity = 0;

            if(keyState[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT]) {
                xVelocity = -5;
            }

            x += xVelocity;
        }
    } 

    KTest() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }
    void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        key_state[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
    void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        key_state[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }
}
```

Base class taken from: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java:Tutorials:Key_States